# Circular mechanics question: finding an expression for T

Tags: circles, classical-mechanics, spheres

The following is an extract from my Further Mechanics 2 book (A level):

[image]

So I had a go at the above problem; here is what I attempted:

[image]

But the actual answer is apparently this:

[image]

Can someone please follow my workings through and point at where I might have gone wrong? (or possibly the mark scheme as this is a first edition copy)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the $m$ inside the square root (as in the "actual answer") is obviously wrong.

Your mistake is here:
$$
T \sin\theta - R \cos\theta = \frac12 T - \frac{\sqrt3}2 R
\neq \frac12 T + \frac{\sqrt3}2 R.
$$

You wrote $T \sin\theta - R \cos\theta$ correctly, but later you wrote
$\frac12 T + \frac{\sqrt3}2 R,$ which was supposed to be the same thing but was not.

If you had written $\frac12 T - \frac{\sqrt3}2 R$ instead,
which is the correct set of substitutions,
I think the rest of your calculations would have come out correct.

Comment: Thanks, classic example of a sign error!

Answer (score 0):

With $\theta = \arctan\left(\frac 12\right) = \frac{\pi}{6}$

Calling

$$
\begin{array}{rcll}
\delta &=& 2 r \sin\theta\cos\theta&\mbox{Mass distance from rotation axis}\\
\vec H &=&\omega^2\delta m(-1,0)&\mbox{Centripetal force}\\
\vec W &=& m g(0,-1)&\mbox{Weigth force}\\
\vec T &=& t(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)&\mbox{Tension in the rod}\\
\vec R &=& r_0(-\cos\theta,\sin\theta)&\mbox{Sphere reaction force}
\end{array}
$$

in equilibrium we have

$$
\vec H+\vec W+\vec T+\vec R = \vec 0
$$

or

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 -2 m r_0\cos\theta \sin\theta \omega ^2-r \cos\theta+t \sin\theta&=&0 \\
 -g m+t \cos\theta+r \sin\theta&=&0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

solving for $t,r_0$ we have

$$
t=\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{3} m \left(2 g+\omega ^2 r\right)\\
r_0 = \frac{1}{4} m \left(2 g-3 \omega ^2 r\right)
$$

The supposed answer with $\sqrt{m}$ cannot be correct. It is not dimensionallly feasible.